# salesforce chatter widget on external pages

Tags: chatter, integration, website-integration

Does Salesforce provide chatter widget for use on legacy pages - i.e. for iframe integration? I found this solution http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/chatter-everywhere-externalizing-chatter-with-heroku-and-the-chatter-rest-ap-is-v3 - looks great for me, but I'd prefer using recommended and supported widget.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. There is a feature request you can vote for:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000KK0vAAG

Although I discover some REST API documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_API